# Toggling Ubuntu bootable USB stick to toggle between UEFI and non UEFI?

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I would like the ability to test store PCs for Ubuntu compatibility by booting them up with an Ubuntu 16.04 bootable USB memory stick.  It is unknown (to me) if all or most new desktops are UEFI secure boot.

My 16.04 bootable USB is not UEFI configured (I made no UEFI configuration inputs when creating the bootable).  **Is it possible to configure a USB bootable so that it's boot mechanism can be 'toggled' for UEFI and non UEFI systems?**  The idea is that with one bootable, it can be possible to boot both UEFI and bios systems, without modifying the PC's boot configuration.

Comment: **mkusb** is a Ubuntu app that makes a Live or Persistent Ubuntu boot drive that works with both UEFI and BIOS. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb. UNetbootin works for both in Windows. https://unetbootin.github.io/

Comment: Almost all systems are compatible. Its just if you want the very newest hardware, it may be a bit before it is fully supported in any distribution. And the more main stream it is, the better.  Very new hardware may require you to manually update kernel & drivers until distribution catches up.  You may be able to find system or similar configuration here: http://openbenchmarking.org/